# New Coder simple time clock

Tags: python

I need help trying to solve this problem in python

You must write a program asking for the current time `(hours only)` and an amount of hours in the future. Use the modulo `%` operator to tell the time traveler the future hour to which they will be traveling.

the tricky part for me is how do you make the time reset after 24

edit

```
`#TODO 1: Ask for user input
hour=input("what time is it?")
time_traveled=input("how many hours would you like to travel")
hr=int(hour)
tt=int(time_traveled)`
`#TODO 2: Calculate the future hour
futurehr=hr+tt
if futurehr%24 == 0:
    finalHr=futurehr
else:annoyinghr=futurehr
    days=annoyinghr%24*24
if annoyinghr%24 > 0:
    finalHr=annoyinghr-days`
```

sorry about not posting the code, I think my problem is I dont understand the `%` well enough

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @idjaw that another text-book comment I'll be saving to my "List of generic comments I'll give to new, misguided, users".

Comment: It tells you how in the problem statement.

Comment: Edit the post rather than pasting this into the comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're making your code more complicated than necessary:

```
# TODO 1: Ask for user input
hour = int(input("What time is it? "))
time_traveled = int(input("How many hours would you like to travel? "))

#TODO 2: Calculate the future hour
future_hour = (hour + time_traveled) % 24

print("You will arrive in the future at", future_hour, "o'clock")
```

If the above isn't sufficient, please edit your description to say what further processing needs to be done to the result.  If it is sufficient, the above isn't finished code --  it really should handle possible bad, non-numeric or out of range input via explicit tests and `try ... except` clauses.